# how to find the file is being deleted from SD card in android

Tags: android

I want to know how to find the file is being deleted from system or how to find which system call is made before file is deleted in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android.os.FileObserver` class. I haven't tried it, but I think it must work.